# How to implement paypal withdrawal with ActiveMerchant

Tags: ruby, paypal, activemerchant

I need to implement both directions of moving money:

- User puts money on his/her balance inside system (from own paypal account)
- User transfers money from his/her inside system balance to own paypal account

Balance inside system is some kind of virtual wallet. User can put money to it from paypal or he/she can get money from other user by committing some operations inside system (for example sell smth to other user). And this number is not a real money until user require to move money to his/her paypal account.

The first point is more-less clear. But I can't find anything about the second one.

I'm using ActiveMerchant gem. Would be nice to get some solution with it.

Comment: Perhaps you should define what `balance inside system` means and link people to what you found that works.